# loop through 2 strings and combine VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

i have a simple task i think

my code generates 2 strings

string A (separated by line feeds)

```
1
2
3
4
```

String B (separated by line feeds)

```
5
6
7
8
```

i am trying to figure out how to combine these separate strings into one as if they were two columns next to each other, separated by a comma

the result would be string C

```
1,5
2,6
3,7
4,8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like?

```
    Dim A As String = "1" & vbCrLf & "2" & vbCrLf & "3" & vbCrLf & "4"
    Dim B As String = "5" & vbCrLf & "6" & vbCrLf & "7" & vbCrLf & "8"
    Debug.Print(A)
    Debug.Print(B)

    Dim tmp As New List(Of String)
    tmp.AddRange(A.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    Dim values() As String = B.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For i As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
        If i <= tmp.Count - 1 Then
            tmp(i) = tmp(i) & "," & values(i)
        Else
            tmp.Add("," & values(i))
        End If
    Next

    Dim C As String = String.Join(vbCrLf, tmp.ToArray)
    Debug.Print(C)
```

Comment: ok, for A and B i already have them in their respective strings. they both have lets say 100 lines each. when i run your code i get all of A but only the first 10 entries on B, even though right before i run your code i have a msgbox display both the contents of A and B, and all the data is there. Also what does appear for B is in the reverse order in which B is (instead of 5,6,7,8 like it is, when it runs in your code i see 8,7,6,5)

Comment: yes, you are right ... i had a mis-named variable in the code. it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert both strings to char[] (Char() - character array) (string.ToCharArray()).

Iterate thru the arrays.

You will need to check boundary conditions (e.g. what if the strings are different lengths).

Comment: lets say my string is holding the data (all numbers), what is the syntax for the conversion? string.ToCharArray(string_a)? and how do i go about iterating through the array?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
'first string
Dim a As String = "abcd"
'second string
Dim b As String = "defghijk"

'Remove Line feeds
Dim tempA As String = a.Replace(vbLf, "")
Dim tempB As String = a.Replace(vbLf, "")
'Get the string with the larger size.
Dim largerSize As Integer = If(tempA.Length > tempB.Length, tempA.Length, tempB.Length)
'We use a string builder to build our new string
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
'Loop on the larger size and only insert if inside range of string
For i As Integer = 0 To largerSize - 1
    If i < tempA.Length Then
        sb.Append(a(i))
        sb.Append(",")
    End If
    If i < tempB.Length Then
        sb.Append(b(i))
    End If

    sb.Append(vbLf)
Next
'this is the result
Dim combined As String = sb.ToString()
```

Edit answer to remove line feeds

Another Edit after string result edited

Another edit to make it VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

I would use the wonderful Linq `Zip`! (I would first `String.Split` the 2 strings with the line-feed character) and then

```
Dim column1() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
Dim column2() As String = {"5", "6", "7", "8"}
Dim mixed= column1.Zip(column2, Function(first, second) first & "," & second)
```

edit:

oh, and then, if you want to have it back into 1 string, you can either use `String.Join` but Linq is fun too! So you can write :

```
Dim mixed= column1.Zip(column2, Function(first, second) first & "," & second)
                  .Select(i => i.Boo)
                  .Aggregate((i, j) => i + vbLf + j)
```

Did I mention that Linq is fun?